# Roulette probabilities "equality"

Tags: probability, geometric-probability, gambling

If a roulette has equal number of two differently coloured "boxes" arranged alternatingly, the probability of a ball landing on either of the colours should be 1/2. If the like coloured "boxes" were instead arranged all next to each other dividing the roulette into two differently coloured "semicircles" would the probabilty of a ball landing on one of the colours still be 50% or not ? Why?

Comment: Presumably it would still be $1/2$, because the two halves of the wheel are symmetric.  Still this is a physical assumption, not strictly a mathematical one.  Any statements about the probability of real-world events are not strictly mathematical.

Comment: I see, it might be worth trying the physics stack exchange as well then. Thanks.